# error in my android eclipse project: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, android-multidex

I'm working in my android application with the google play services 3 I want to upgrade it to the version 11.2.0 unfortunately there is some packages that no longer exists in the newer version like the packages below:

```
 com.google.android.gms.internal.as;
 com.google.android.gms.internal.i;
 com.google.android.gms.internal.m;
 com.google.android.gms.location.R.string;
```

So I had to keep both of the libraries ( version 3 and version 11.2.0) the project now is clean from errors but I have this error while trying to execute the application

```
[2017-08-15 11:41:55 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 
[2017-08-15 11:41:55 - MyApplication] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

Notice: I'm working with eclipse

Comment: your methods count is exceeding the threshold, enable the multidexing in your app.
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: Thank you,
 but the problem is that I can't find how to enable it under an eclipse project.

Comment: I was forced to move to Android Studio (away from my favorite Eclipse) as Google writes all docs etc on this. Enabling multidex in graddle/android studio is easy.

Comment: you have to move to gradle build in your eclipse project to use multidexing. otherwise move to android studio.